# Trigger Enter Event on keypressed Javasccript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want my textbox trigger an event through enter and runs a function, here's my input form and pretend the submitting of form is disabled...

```
<input type="text" name="webURL" value="" id="urlField" onkeypress="enterKey(event){ checkURL(this) }" />
```

Now after inputting something on text box, and enter was triggered by this enter event verification below:

```
function enterKey(e){
        var keycode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if(keycode == 13){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Whenever it verifies that the user trigger enter it returns true otherwise false. I think i'm messing something on the input form `keypress` function. Anyone can tell me how to do that to make it work and run the `checkURL()` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
onkeypress="if(enterKey(event)){ checkURL(this) }"
```

But it's a better practice separate js from markup. Using a js frameworks, such as jQuery, helps a lot..